# Where to get a frequency sorted dictionary available for use in free software?

Tags: database, dictionary, compression

I need a frequency-sorted dictionary for a compression program, (permissive or GPLv3 compatible license), but haven't the slightest clue where to get one under such a license (all had missing or bad copyright notices). Would anyone have recommendations as to where to get one? I've looked for a while, but my only option seems to be creating my own, which I doubt the effective quality of, using e-books. (it would not be wholly representative of all English, much less modern English, my target.)

PS: about 200,000-50,000 words is a good target. Huge files is not a good idea.

Comment: @bmargulies Why not? Information should be free. f this isn't done yet, I'll just do my best to make my own and paste it on the interwebz for free. Though I assume the quality would be lower than if it's been done by a professional. (of course, it would take me quite a while, so I was hoping it's already done)

Comment: You could use a more modern corpus, such as wikipedia articles or something.

Comment: I can't use a bot to scan wikipedia though can I?

Comment: Is that the same "Information should be free" where some information is more free than others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a unigram distribution built over a large quantity of representative English text. A 'unigram distribution' is the formal term for what you're calling a 'dictionary with frequencies'.

Google published a giant collection of ngrams under a permissive license.

See http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html.

Or http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets.

If you don't need all those obscure words, then just chop the distribution to what you want.

As for licensing, even the FSF says that the GPL is inapplicable to dictionaries. They aren't 'source'. So the CC license here works perfectly fine for incorporating in whatever.

If you don't care about having entirely representative data, then download the wikipedia dumps and the Ruby tool for extracting text, and do your own unigram distribution.

Whatever you choose, you'll be working with *a lot of data* if you want useful results.

Comment: Problem #1, this is a bit too much information to bundle with a data compressor. Problem #2 it's non-GPL compatible, and not usable in free software. It's also unsorted data. Just opening one of the files lagged the foobar out my computer, it used 6GiB ram before I terminated the text editor since it started swapping.

Comment: Of course it can be used in free software. It's an unrestricted creative commons license.  If it has too many words for you, chop off the infrequent ones.

Comment: Then I supposed it's useful, but doesn't answer the question none the less, the mass of random data could hardly be called "sorted".

Comment: Any professional in the NLP field would call this a perfectly useful resource, as sorting it in to the order of interest is a trivial task.

Comment: Someone extracted the top 10k unigrams by frequency here: https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: http://norvig.com/ngrams/

Contains this, which might be what you need:

1. 4.9 MB count_1w.txt - The 1/3 million most frequent words, all lowercase, with counts. (Called vocab_common in the chapter, but I changed file names here.)
2. 5.6 MB count_2w.txt - The 1/4 million most frequent two-word (lowercase) bigrams, with counts.